# Why does my mouse pointer change when typing?

Tags: fedora, mate-desktop

I have a Mate spin of Fedora 28. I hadn't used it for a while, but I don't recall seeing this problem originally (I may be wrong though.) When I'm typing in Gnome Terminal, (or anything else for that matter), my mouse pointer changes from the standard "insert text" cursor to something resembling cursive writing that I can't read. I've attached photos for reference.

If anyone can tell me how to disable this, I'd appreciate it.

**Before I start typing:**
[image: image before I start typing]

**After I type something:**
[image: image after typing]

Comment: A lot of people are, like I did, going to look at that and start by wondering why you think that the cursor changes shape, because it is a block in both images.  You might want to avoid the confusion by using a name such as _mouse pointer_.

Comment: Good call, I hadn't thought of that, I will edit the post now. Thank you!

Comment: I just want to clear up - this is not normal, so it's not just a matter of editing some config file.

Comment: Well I've heard of settings to change pointers to other images for various situations (windows has these settings) so my assumption is that it was a configurable setting, but if not, it's still something I'd like to fix.

Answer (score 0):

You probably enabled an input method by pressing <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>*Space*</kbd>.

The Fedora [documentation](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/14/html/User_Guide/sect-User_Guide-Customizing_the_desktop-Customizing_input_methods.html) tells how to enable/disable the feature.

> To enable, disable, or select the type of input method in GNOME, click *System* → *Preferences* → *Input Method*